# What are the best methods for conducting usability testing with people who are neither experts nor end-users?

Tags: usability-testing, usability-study

My team and I have developed a prototype of an augmented reality mobile application for teaching primary school students human anatomy.

We are going to do a usability testing and evaluation with the primary school students using FUN toolkit, and we are also going to conduct an expert review using heuristic evaluation and cognitive walkthrough.

Furthermore, we also want the teachers to test the app, and to evaluate the usability in the context of their students' usage. However, the teachers are neither usability experts nor end-users so what is the most appropriate method for them regarding usability testing, survey design etc?

Comment: What is the reason why you can't get end-users involved? You mentioned that the AR application is for teaching primary school students anatomy, so it seems like there would be both a teacher and student component to the application, since the classroom teaching environment involves interaction between teachers and students.

Comment: My end-users are the students and for sure I am conducting a usability testing with them. Nevertheless, I also want to know what the teachers think about the app since they have to accept and integrate it into their lessons. So maybe I am just thinking a bit too complicated. I am actually struggling with the task of finding good questions for the teachers and so I asked myself if there are guidelines or templates available for that.

Answer (score 1):

My gut answer is that you shouldn't **usability test** the teachers in the scenario you described. **I'm not saying you shouldn't talk to teachers.** Just that you should adjust your goals.

Instead, you should be validating product/market fit with that audience. You're asking **IF the tool has the correct features and or content** for them to feel comfortable implementing it in their classrooms.

---

### Questions I would ask:

1. Can you see a use for this tool in your classroom? why/why not?
2. Does the content and order match up with how you typically teach this topic? If not how do we change it?
3. What questions or topics do you struggle to convey to your students? How might this thing we made fit into that process?
4. Do your students have access to the technology platforms this product requires? If so where? Is every student given one? Do you expect access from home?
5. Have we shown you anything that seems to be extra or gets in the way of implementing this in your classroom?